# repeat several times link add and remove after add new input. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why after each times `add` and `remove` `new input` link `remove` and `add` repeat several times?
like: `removeremoveremoveremove` or `addaddaddaddaddaddadd` and `...`

EXAMPLE(add input and see it): http://jsfiddle.net/zgWr3/6/

```
$(function () {
    $('a.add_input').live('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $class = '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class');
        var newDiv = $(this).closest($class).clone();
        $(this).closest($class).find('.add_input').remove()
        //$(this).find('.adda').remove()
        newDiv.find('.adda .mediumCell').append('<a href="" class="remove_input">remove</a>')
        newDiv.find('input').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', false).val('');
        });
        $($class + ':last').after(newDiv);
        //newDiv.remove('.adda')
        //alert(newDiv)
    });

    $('a.remove_input').live('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $class = '.' + $(this).closest('div.find_input').find('div').attr('class');
        $(this).closest($class).prev().find('.adda .mediumCell').append('<a href="" class="add_input">add</a>')
        $(this).closest($class).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're cloning the div, which contains the link, then adding another.

edit: well you clone the div then add it, and append a remove_link (and a similarly for the add_link in remove).  The first time there is no link, it works.  The 2nd time the link exists when you call clone(), so you add a duplicate.  The 3rd time 2 links exist, and you add another.  And so on.

It might be best to build out the whole HTML of the field outside the function, something like:

```
var divHTML = \'
  <div class="field">\
    <input type="text"/>\
    <a class="remove_link">Remove</a>\
  </div>';
```

... then simply adding `$(divHTML)` inside your function, rather than this complex cloning/appending/manipulating function you have now.  In any case there is probably a simpler and more straightforward way to do this.

edit 2: Something like this

```
var divHTML = '\
  <div class="mediumCell">\
    <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="hello" title="تعرفه"\
     class="numeric" style="width: 70px;">\
    <a class="remove_input" href="#">remove</a>\
  </div>';

$('a.add_input').live('click', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(divHTML).insertBefore($(this));      
});

$('a.remove_input').live('click', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('.mediumCell').remove();
});
```

edit 3:

Well, you can always use your original add function and just throw a not() filter in there, so the link only gets added on the first clone:

```
newDiv.find('.adda .mediumCell').not(':has(.remove_input)').append('<a href="" class="remove_input">remove</a>')
```

Comment: Is it possible for you that give me example?

Comment: my divHTML Is not fixed Is changing. I used several different HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a new "remove" link each time the "add" link is clicked from this code:

```
newDiv.find('.adda .mediumCell').append('<a href="" class="remove_input">remove</a>')
```

Commenting that out it works fine, but then you don't have any "remove" link at all. I would recommend adding that "remove" link outside of the live event and manipulating it there if you need to.

Comment: Is it possible for you that give me example?